# Problem when running tensorflow in venv (virtual enviromnemt)

Tags: tensorflow, virtual

(env - Windows10, using NVIDIA gpu, Powershell)

I wanna run this sample code below in virtual environment

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', 
                input_shape=(32,32,1)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

There was an error that failed to register the GPU when the code was executed, but the execution was successful without using the GPU.

```
(venv) PS E:\lolol> & e:/lolol/venv/Scripts/python.exe e:/lolol/testcode2.py
2021-12-01 03:35:40.545756: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:40.546020: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-12-01 03:35:45.107760: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:45.108720: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:45.109629: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:45.110607: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:45.111655: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:45.112802: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:45.113631: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:45.114479: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-12-01 03:35:45.114979: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-12-01 03:35:45.116383: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 32, 32, 100)       200

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 32, 32, 50)        5050

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 32, 32, 5)         255

=================================================================
Total params: 5,505
Trainable params: 5,505
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I know that CUDA should be installed when running tensorflow in a virtual environment, so I installed it, but it still does not run properly.

Perhaps CUDA is installed on drive C, which is the default installation path, and the venv folder is installed on drive E, which is another drive, so there seems to be a problem. I think CUDA should be installed on a drive with VENV, but I'm not sure exactly where to install the program. In the VENV folder? Anywhere in the E drive?

Comment: Did you have installed `Cudnn` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow indicates that you need CUDA 11.0 here (in "cudartxx_110" and "cublas_110", "110"=11.0 is the version required). Do you have precisely the good version? Check it using `ls /usr/local/cuda*`. Moreover you need CudNN, the version 8.0, otherwise your tensorflow can't run with GPU.
You can check this very usefull link to get the CUDA/CuDNN version required by every versions of tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu (here you seem to have tf 2.4)
I recommend you Python>=3.7 + Cuda 11.2 + CuDNN 8.1 (it is what I have) and then you can run the most recent versions of tf in your environments (+ Pytorch and even JAX)